# Step to installing thingsboard on AWS EC2

Tags: thingsboard

My requirement is installing thingsboard on AWS, i have got the docuemnt on thingsboard official website to install thingsboard on AWS EC2 "https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/aws/" but there is not define all step.

Comment: Also, I need the same requirement.